# Font is rendered different on iPad than on desktop

Tags: html, css, fonts

Check out [this site](http://feelgoodfood.se), as you can see the menu renders properly on desktop but on the iPad the font seem to get much bigger, causing a line break. Could it be because the font im using isn't loaded, and it uses the second instead (Times New Roman)? That sounds very plausable since i achieve the same result if i use only TNR, but how can i make the font smaller if Times New Roman is used instead of my first choice of font?

Answer (score -1):

I am not seeing any change in font size for iPad 1 and iPad2.

http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Comment: Screenfly doesn't render as Safari or Chrome do in the iPad apparently, it only seems to emulate the resolution.

Comment: It didn't even have the correct device-width for mobile phones, just changed the resolution...